# Flutter: Will callback supplied to Timer get fired when application goes to background

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, timer

**In Flutter if I create a `Timer`, will the supplied callback get executed if the application is in background?**

I think documentation is not clear on this or I might have missed it (please supply a link if you find it anywhere).
I just tried doing this with a timer set up to 10 seconds and it works fine.

I assume that is approach is not very reliable and other methods<sup>`*`</sup> should be used instead. I think if the app is paused/terminated by operating system to preserve battery or due to low memory, nothing will be executed. But for me this situation could be an ok approach.

`*` I know there are isolates so I guess I could spawn the timer inside one of these. Downside is that the isolate must be regular function (or static method) so no access to application data in my scenario. Then there are different scheduling packages etc but I'm trying to avoid these for now. I know about background tasks but I'm really looking for an answer on code execution using timers.

Comment: you should make background service to do the work

Comment: Thanks but I’m looking for an answer to question in first paragraph.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service ... In this package you can use timer in background

Comment: Look, I appreciate the help but it's not an answer to my question. I want to know specifically what happens when timers are involved while the app is in background.